# Are const arguments of function are passed by reference automatically?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If I have a code that look like following:

```
void foofunc(const int fooarg)
{
    // something here
}
```

Is `fooarg` passed by value or by reference? As `fooarg` is `const` it is not gonna get modified, so it is ok if it is passed by reference.

---

And if I have a code that look like following:

```
void foofunc(int fooarg)
{
    // something here, but fooarg is not gonna get modified
}
```

Will `fooarg` be passed by value or by reference, also will it be const or not? Situation is same as above. It is not gonna get modified.

Comment: The signature doesn't specify that the arguments are passed by reference (&) or as pointers (*), so they are passed by value. Why the question? Have you encountered a problem?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference when... they are passed by reference.  There's nothing confusing here, your argument is passed by value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought maybe compiler optimizes the code :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos For example, when I have a function like this: `void foofunc(std:vector<int> v);` and if I pass very large `vector`, then efficiency reduces :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, I haven't encountered any problem. I'm a competitive programmer. And it is good to know if it is optimized or not. :)

Comment: It's not a matter of optimization. Many times you *do* want to work an a copy of the data - parallel processing is at least one case. You should use references or copy semantics as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the language level, if you pass it by value then, of course, it is passed by value, not by reference. But how the passing is implemented physically under the hood is an implementation detail, which is not that dependent on the argument being `const` as it might seem at the first sight.

In many compiler implementations, "large" arguments passed by value (from the language point of view) are actually passed *by reference* under the hood and then a copy is made by the prologue code of the function itself. The function body uses the copy, which creates the end effect of the parameter being received *by value*.

In other implementations the argument is literally passed "by value", i.e. the copy is prepared in advance, by the caller.

The advantage of the former approach is that knowing the inner workings of the function, the compiler might decide not to make a copy when it knows that a copy is not needed (e.g. when the function body makes no attempts to modify the parameter value). Note that a smart compiler can perform this analysis and eliminate unnecessary copying regardless of whether the corresponding argument is declared as `const`.

This is a matter of optimal code generation, not governed by the language specification. However, such matters might be specified by platform-dependent ABI specs.

Comment: "e.g. when the function body makes no attempts to modify the parameter value" It's not only that this function doesn't modify the parameter, the compiler also needs to make sure that the variable passed in the calling scope cannot be modified on another thread or by another function on the same thread.

Answer (score 8):

The declaration says it is passed by value. So it is passed by value.

Answer (score 4):

It is passed by value because the declaration says it is passed by value.

> It is not going to get modified, so it is OK if it is passed by reference.

No so, but otherwise. Another thread might modify the variable passed. In which case passing by reference would change the semantics.

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but what you mean by "another thread"?

Comment: I think I got you. If I run two threads simultaneously and one of which is `foofunc` and the other one is `void wackyfunc(int &fooarg)` which modifies fooarg, then things gonna get confusing. :) Thanks.

Comment: Even with a single thread, the variable could still be modified in the middle of the function.

Answer (score 3):

A top-level `const` is ignored in function signatures, so these declarations are completlely equivalent:

```
void foofunc(const int fooarg);
void foofunc(int fooarg);
```

It follows that the semantics of both are pass-by-value. Of course, a compiler is allowed to optimize this following the "as-if" rule, so given enough information, it is allowed to use reference semantics.

Comment: They're not completely equivalent -- in the body of the first function, you wouldn't be able to set fooarg to a different value, but in the second function you could.

Comment: This is true, but this is irrelevant. The question is not about the function type at language level, but rather about the inner workings of the implementation.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner They are identical *declarations*. A `const` in teh *definition* means you cannot modify your copy of the argument. But if you were to provide `const` and non-`const` definitions, you would get a mutiple definition error.

Comment: Either it is ignored or it isn't, and it isn't. It's not irrelevant. And it doesn't follow from the fact that they are equivalent for even some purposes that that they are both passed by value. It follows from the absence of '&'.

Comment: @EJP It is ignored for anything other than what can be done with the parameter *inside* the body of the function. The signatures are treated as identical by the language, so they are semantically equivalent.